# Node Script rendering differently on localhost vs Codepen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to mess around with MEAN more and I'm following [Thinkster's Tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#opening-rest-routes). I'm at the portion where I move on to Node.JS But I've been having quite a few issues up to this point, and I'm fairly confident it isn't in my Code.

I finally decided to load it via 'npm start' and on localhost it's still looking incorrect. I'm not seeing comments majority of the time, sometimes I do but the {{comments}} etc aren't resolving. I assumed originally it was due to opening the file locally, so thought NPM could fix it.

I'm using 'Brackets', which was good until it turned into EJS then it couldn't live preview it anymore.

What's confusing me is I posted it onto Codepen and the site is working fairly normally (Except clicking a title doesn't go back to index, but I don't believe we ever made that controller.

**My Index.ejs**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flapper News</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
    <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
  </div>

 <form ng-submit="addComment()"
  style="margin-top:30px;">
  <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Comment"
    ng-model="body"></input>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
 </form>

</script>

<body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <ui-view></ui-view>

            <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
                    ng-click="upvote(post)"></span>
                {{post.upvotes}}
                <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
                    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                        {{post.title}}
                    </a>
                    <span ng-hide="post.link">
                        {{post.title}}
                    </span>
                        <span>
                            <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
                        </span>
                </span>
            </div>

            <form ng-submit="addPost()"
                style="margin-top:30px;">
                <h3>Add a new post</h3>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Title"
                        ng-model="title"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Link"
                        ng-model="link"></input>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My angularApp.JS**

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }).state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

app.factory('posts', [function(){
    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
function($scope, posts){
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title,
            link: $scope.link,
            upvotes: 0,
            comments: [
                {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
            ]
        });
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.link = '';
    }
    $scope.upvote = function(post){
        post.upvotes++;
    }
}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$stateParams',
'posts',
function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
    $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
    $scope.addComment = function(){
        if($scope.body === '') { return; }
        $scope.post.comments.push({
            body: $scope.body,
            author: 'user',
            upvotes: 0
        });
        $scope.body = '';
    };
}]);
```

Originally I did assume it was due to it being local, but wouldn't NPM resolve that? If not, what's the best way to truly test Node/Express while you work on it?

Appreciate any insight.

(I've looked around SO and I see a lot of posts with similar issues to mine, but none answered directly/updated)

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "flapper-news",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.4.1",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.9",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

**Adding in Console.Log**

My Console is returning a 404 GET Response. Unsure why.

```
angular.js:9818GET http://localhost:3000/home.html 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9818m @ angular.js:9619Ke.$get.f @ angular.js:9335(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13175$eval @ angular.js:14388$digest @ angular.js:14204$apply @ angular.js:14493(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1449e @ angular.js:4182d @ angular.js:1447sc @ angular.js:1467Jd @ angular.js:1361(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26086a @ angular.js:2741c @ angular.js:3011
angular.js:9818 GET http://localhost:3000/home.html 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9818m @ angular.js:9619Ke.$get.f @ angular.js:9335(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13175$eval @ angular.js:14388$digest @ angular.js:14204$apply @ angular.js:14493l @ angular.js:9650O @ angular.js:9840w.onload @ angular.js:9781
```

Comment: Since you're referencing `npm start` here would be good to include your package.json so we can see what that's actually running, also not really clear to me what the question is here.  I know something isn't working but not clear what?  Have you looked into the network inspector to see what loads and what doesn't any errors in the console, what's happening what do you expect?  (is it just that you see interpolation braces like {{}} in the view? typically this means you have angular errors in the console cause something didn't parse or the page didn't process cause angular didn't load)

Comment: Hey @shaunhusain - It isn't rendering, at all. In the sense instead of showing the topic name 'foo' it shows {{post.title} and the link doesn't reflect the controller, either.

Comment: any errors in the console should be something there? if there are no errors in the console next thing I'd check is the network tab filter for angular.js and check the response actually loads angular.js source up... angular waits for DOMContentReady then starts parsing the page looking for an ng-app directive first one it finds it triggers the bootstrap process for (does config then run blocks then starts looking for more directives to process).

Comment: Hello @shaunhusain - Sorry I should have said in my reply. I pasted the console.log above - There is one, and it re-iterates every time I try to click a {[post.title}}

It seems like it can't load the template that it had my setup?

Comment: DNorthrup ah I should have been a bit more explicit though good to include those server side console errors/logs as well, what I meant was F12 in Chrome and the console there and also Network Tab in that Chrome Console (also works in Firefox and I think modern IE has decent debug tools as well)

Comment: @shaunhusain Ah, sorry. Checked network
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angularApp.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

And I see the code in the console. What's confusing me is why it works perfectly fine in CodePen but not Localhost. Makes me wonder if maybe I need to modify something in 'app.js'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121300/discussion-between-shaunhusain-and-dnorthrup).

Answer (score 0):

It says it can't find `home.html`. Your url in `home` state is probably wrong. This url is relative to your `index.html` file so double check that.

Comment: I didn't even think about that. I assumed since I'm using templates, it wouldn't matter. So I updated them to 'views/{{templateUrl}}' and the 404 went away, but it still didn't load anything.

Comment: Not at all. Discussing with someone else and they think it may be a cache issue, and the page is loading before Angular. Unsure.